# like and regexp_like

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-like

For like we have %. for ex: if we give ad% it ll fetch all the records which starts with ad but i should use regexp_like. for regexp_like what can be used so that it acts as % for like. i cant use ^ad because from UI we ll give something like ad* to fetch.

Before query:select * from employee where fname like 'pr%';

Present query:select * from employee where regexp_like(fname ,'pr+');

for present query i m getting the values which contains pr but i want to get values which starts with pr.

Testdata: if pr* is given then i should get program etc i.e the value which starts with pr.

Comment: could you add your query so we can see what you are trying to do? also maybe some test data and expected result

Comment: is my question clear now?

Comment: first of all you are using regexp wrong, the correct syntax afaik is "...where regexp_like(fname, 'pr+')" and I think the wildcard character for regexp_like is a period "." so you would need 'pr.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (fname, '^pr(*)');
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e1f1a/1)

This one also seems to work as far as I can tell:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (fname, '^pr.');
```

Or another one that works:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE regexp_like(fname,'^pr');
```

Comment: that's what we're here for, no problem

Comment: hey jeremy i m trying 
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE regexp_like(fname,'n$'); to fetch the values which ends with n but $ is not working ..:( can u help me...

Comment: should be something like "regexp_like(fname,'(*)n$');" , actually n$ should work to, you might need to trim your fname if it's not a varchar field (if it's a normal char(20) or something)

Comment: @Alén try this: "WHERE regexp_like(trim(fname),'n$');"

Answer (score 0):

Check below link regexp_like -

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

If still not able to reslove your issue then as pointed by Jeremy share test data and expected result. That will help to reslove.

Check below example

```
create table a 
(b varchar2(150));

insert into a values ('Pravin');

insert into a values ('TestPravin');

select * from a where REGEXP_LIKE (B, '^Pra');
```

Comment: I have provided the query and test data.

Comment: @Alén I have added example for you